# Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '<path to src>/includes/php.content-header.php'

Tags: xampp

I was going through some instructions to set up a mock website through  xampp for development purposes, but ran into an issue. The instructions are as follows:

```
Clone this repository
Install PHP and MySQL, and php5-mysql
Changes to php.ini
    auto_prepend_file=<path to src>/includes/php.content-header.php
    short_tag=On
Get the most recent DB Dump and load it into MySQL
Create user sitename_login with password from includes/class.mysql_db.php
Grant this user permissions to sitename_site
```

Running local server
Desktop Version

```
From sitename.com directory run
    php -S localhost:8000
```

As far as I know I followed the instructions as I should have, but when trying to open up php documents in xampp I got this error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '<path to src>/includes/php.content-header.php' (include_path='.;F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

The folder layout in xampp is `xampp->htdocs->folderName->includes->php.content-header.php`

I've tried changing the location of the folders, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. I tried editing the contents of `php.ini`, but I was getting the same exact error even if I took out `/includes/` out of the `auto_prepend_file`.

Any clues as to what I could do to get past this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `require(<path to src>/includes/php.content-header.php)` in your file and change it to `require(__DIR__ . "\\includes\\php.content-header.php")` (assuming your are on Windows)

Comment: I'm still having issues seeing changes made to the php.ini file.

Comment: Use the absolute path: C:\xamp\htdocs\includes\php.content-header.php.  And also make sure the file exists.